# How to increase size of the Spotlight search results window? - window fixed in width since BigSur?

Tags: spotlight, big-sur

Since the last macOS update BigSur 11.2 the width of the Spotlight bar has been narrowed. In addition, there seems to be no possibility to widen the window when hovering over by the mouse. The window can be pulled longer in height but not width.

Therefor search results are displayed rather small.

Any suggestions? What am I missing?